# Scala in java code : $colon

Tags: syntax, scala, bytecode

I read some java source code which including Scala source code.

I found `Nil.$colon$colon(Object arg)`

What does keywords `$colon` mean?
And what does this line mean?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

$colon is a mangling for the symbol :.
Since : (and other letters) is an illegal letter in java for method names but allowed in scala, a strategy is needed to encode it into a legal name. Hence, the $colon

Here your code translate to arg :: Nil which adds arg to the empty list, constructing a List with arg as single element.

Comment: Since I understand your answer, I would like to ask: What does 'mangling' mean exactly?

Comment: It basically means having a different identifier used for the runtime than is present in the source code.
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling .